# Strange behavior on jQuery append() when sorting table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was looking for a method to sort my very complex table, and found this approach which is working perfectly:

( completed code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/sg552sg552/Lsw6mnh4/15/
 )

my html code is:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>string</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

and my js code is:

```
$('th').click(function() {  
  var table =  $(this).parents('table').eq(0);
  var rows = table.find('tr:gt(0)').toArray().sort(comparer($(this).index()));
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    console.info("== before append, rows count: " + $(table).find('tr').size() )
    // WHY doesn't this "append" increase the total tr size ? 
    table.append(rows[i]);    
    console.info("== after append, rows count: " + $(table).find('tr').size() )    
  }
})

function comparer(index) {  
  return function(a, b) {      
    var valA = getCellValue(a, index),
      valB = getCellValue(b, index);
    return $.isNumeric(valA) && $.isNumeric(valB) ?  valA - valB  : valA.localeCompare(valB)  ;
  }
}

function getCellValue(row, index) {
  return $(row).children('td').eq(index).html();
}
```

The function( sorting the table) works perfectly, but I just wonder, why the "append()" function doesn't increase the "tr" count while there's no place to "remove" any "tr" ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the jQuery `append` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

> You can also select an element on the page and insert it into another:
>
> `$( ".container" ).append( $( "h2" ) );`
>
> If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned)

So the elements are really just being shuffled, not created/destroyed

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not actually appending a 'tr', you're just finding the ones that already exist, putting them into an array, and sorting them. You're not actually telling your code to append any 'tr's to the table.